# IndexedDB - Can't pass variable after onsuccess when opening database

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, web-storage

I have been looking for assistance with setting up an IndexedDB for web storage, and I have run into a problem that I cannot find a good answer to. After I have successfully setup/opened the database I am having trouble passing the variable that contains the database information to access it later. Here is my code, I have been following a guide from MDN :

```
const DB_NAME = 'database-name';
const DB_VERSION = 2;
const DB_STORE_NAME = 'users';

var db;

function openDb() {
   console.log('openDb ...')
   var request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);

   request.onsuccess = function(event) {
       db = request.result;
       console.log("openDb DONE");
   };

   request.onerror = function(event) {
       console.log(request.errorCode);
   };

   request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
       console.log('openDb.onupgradeneeded');
       var store = event.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'id',    autoIncrement: true });

       store.createIndex('age', 'age', { unique: false });
   };
}

function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
    var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
    return tx.objectStore(store_name);
}
```

When `getObjectStore` is called the variable `db` is undefined. My knowledge of javascript is very limited and some concepts I don't get. The guide doesn't not show anything special being done and their demo works as is. Some other guides have mentioned implementing a callback, but they don't show how its done nor do I understand the concept of callbacks. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: IndexedDB is asynchronous, meaning that the events like `onsuccess`, `onupgradeneeded` and `onerror` are triggered in a different time loop. The reason why variable `db` is undefined is because at the time `getObjectStore` is being called, the `onsuccess` hasn't finished yet (e.g. hasn't finished setting the variable `db` with a decent value). If you would set a `setTimeout` of 3 seconds around the section you call `getObjectStore`, you can see what happens ;)

Comment: wow, never thought to put a setTimeout to see if that would give it time to set it. I guess I assumed it wasn't getting set because I could never log it but that was only because I was trying to quick. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, this means that the logical execution order you might have in your script, where you expect one to be executed after the other, might be a complete different order, depending on how long each function (or event) takes to finish. I've been building a wrapper library for IndexedDB for the past few days just because of the same reasons, it's too low-level and takes to much time to write anything useful for a developer. I could post a snippet of the idea but in general it takes a bit of time to get used to the fact that the connection to the database is asynchronous.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you need to learn about a relatively complicated concept usually referred to as asynchronous JavaScript before proceeding to use indexedDB. There are already several thousand questions related to AJAX on stackoverflow. I am trying to think of the most polite way to say this, but basically, the answer you are looking for is already provided by these other questions, and by many other websites. Nevertheless, here are some quick tips.

First, your approach is never going to work. You cannot skip over learning about async.

Second, do not use the setTimeout trick to get it to work. That is horrible advice.

Third, at a general level, a callback is simply a word used to describe a function when the function is used in a particular way. Specifically, a callback refers to a function that is passed as an argument to another function, where the other function then maybe calls the function at some later point in time. More specifically, a callback is generally a function that is called at the end of the function it is passed to, when the function has completed.

For example:

```
function a(b) { alert(b); }
function c(d) { d('hi'); }
c(a);
```

That might look a bit confusing at first but it is the simplest thing I can describe off the top of my head. In the example, the final line calls function c and passes in function a. The effect of the code is that you see 'hi' as a browser alert. In this example, the function a is passed as a parameter/argument to function c. Function c uses the name d for its one and only argument. c calls d with the string 'hi'. When describing this example, we would say that argument d represents a callback function passed to function c. We could also say that function a is the particular callback function used by function c. So that is basically it. When you pass a function in as an argument and the other function calls the passed in argument, you are using a callback.

Then things gets way more complicated, because you have to learn about how to read and write asynchronous code. Properly introducing it would take several pages. Here is an extreme crash course.
You have traditionally been writing synchronous code, even if you did not call it that. Synchronous code runs exactly when you expect it to, in the order that you write your statements. Here is a brief example of typical sync code:

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }
alert(sum(1, 2));
```

Simple stuff. The next example is code that uses a callback, but is still synchronous.

```
function doOperation(op, num1, num2) { return op(num1, num2); }
function sumOperation(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; }
var result = doOperation(sumOperation, 1, 2);
alert(result);
```

Here we passed the sumOperation function into the doOperation function. sumOperation is the callback function. It is the first argument with the name 'op'. Still pretty simple stuff. Now consider the next example. The point of the next example is to show how we *pass control* to the function to do something. Kind of like how goto/labels work.

```
function doOperation(op, num1, num2) {
  var result = op(num1, num2);
  alert(result);
  return undefined;
}
function sumOperation(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; }
doOperation(sumOperation, 1, 2);
```

Notice how doOperation no longer returns a value. It has the logic within its function body. So once we call doOp, the browser starts running the code inside doOperation. So we switched from the outer context into the body of the function.  Also, because doOperation doesn't return anything, we cannot do anything with its return value. The logic is locked inside the body of the doOperation function. The code still works about the same, its just that now we are not returning anything from doOperation, and now the logic is inside doOperation instead of outside in the main/global context.

Now an example that uses setTimeout. This is completely unrelated to the suggestion of using setTimeout.

```
function doOperation(op, num1, num2) {
  setTimeout(function runLater() {
    var result = op(num1, num2);
    alert(result);
    return undefined;      
  }, 1000);
  return undefined;
}
function sumOperation(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; }
doOperation(sumOperation, 1, 2);
```

The point here is to understand that we use a callback (named runLater in this example), and that the code inside the callback *does not run immediately*. Therefore, we can no longer say it runs synchronously. We instead refer to the statements constituting the body of the callback function as asynchronous. So now an alert appears after 1 second. Notice how we cannot return anything from runLater. Also notice how we cannot return anything from doOperation.  There is nothing to return. There is no way to get the value in the 'result' variable out of the scope of runLater.  It is locked in there.

Let's try almost the same thing, but try to have runLater set a variable. Also, I am going to omit 'return undefined' because that is what every function without a explicit return statement returns.

```
var aGlobalResult = null;
function doOperation(op, num1, num2) {
  setTimeout(function runLater() {
    aGlobalResult = op(num1, num2);
  }, 1000);
}
function sumOperation(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; }
doOperation(sumOperation, 1, 2);
alert(aGlobalResult);
```

Hopefully you are catching on to the problem. First off, runLater does not return anything, so doOperation does not return anything, so we could not even try to do something like `aGlobalResult = doOperation(...);`, because that would not make any sense. Second, the result here is that you will see an alert 'undefined' because the alert statement executes prior to the statement that assigns a value to aGlobalResult.  This is even though you wrote the assignment statement higher up (earlier) in the code, and the alert is later. This is the brick wall some newer developers run into right here. This is indeed confusing for some.  aGlobalResult is undefined here because setTimeout does not set it until later. Even if we passed in 0 milliseconds to setTimeout, it is still 'later', meaning that the assignment happens at a later point in time, after the alert. The alert message is always going to be undefined. There is absolutely nothing you can do to avoid the way this works. Nothing. Period. Stop trying. Learn it, or give up entirely.

So, how does one typically write code that behaves or involves asynchronous stuff? By using callbacks. Which again means that you can no longer use return statements to assign values to outer scope variables. You instead want to write functions and pass around control to various functions. In other words, instead of:

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}
a(); b(); c();
```

you write code like this:

```
function a(callback) {  
  var asdf = 1+2; // do some stuff in a
  alert('a finished');
  // a has now completed, call its callback function, appropriately named callback
  callback();
}

function b(callback) {
  var asdfasdfasdf = 3 + 4;
  alert('b finished');

  // call the callback
  callback();
}

a( function(){ b(function() { alert('both a and b finished'); }); });
```

This is more formally known as [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), or CPS.

So, that is an example of the very basics of writing callback functions and basic asynchronous code. Now you can start to use indexedDB. The first thing you will notice is that the function indexedDB.open is documented as asynchronous. So, how can we use it? Like this:

```
var someGlobalVariable = null;

var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
openRequest.onsuccess = function openRequestOnSuccessCallbackFunction(event) {
  // Get a reference to the database variable. If this function is ever called at some later 
  // point in time, the database variable is now defined as the 'result' property of the 
  // open request. There are multiple ways to access the result property. Any of the following
  // lines works 100% the same way. Use whatever you prefer. It does not matter.
  var databaseConnection = openRequest.result;
  var databaseConnection = this.result;
  var databaseConnection = event.target.result;
  var databaseConnection = event.currentTarget.result;


  // Now that we have a valid and defined databaseConnection variable, do something with it
  // e.g.:
  var transaction = databaseConnection.transaction(...);
  var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(...);
  // etc.

  // DO NOT DO THE FOLLOWING, it does not work. Why? Review the early descriptions. First off
  // this onsuccess callback function does not return anything. Second off this function gets 
  // called at some *later* point in time, who knows when. It could be a nanosecond later.
  someGlobalVariable = databaseConnection;
};
```

Hopefully that sets you on the path.

Edit: I thought I would add a bit more of an intro. A related concept you need to learn that I did not explain clearly enough regarding control is the difference between imperative and declarative programming.

Imperative programming involves executing a series of statements in the order you wrote. *You* are the caller and are in control. Imperative code looks like this (fictional code):

```
var dbConn = dbFactory.newConnection('mydb');
var tx = dbConn.newTransaction();
var resultCode = tx.put(myObject);
if(resultCode == dbResultConstants.ERROR_PUT_KEY_EXISTS) {
  alert('uhoh');
}
```

Declarative programming is subtly different. With a declarative approach, you write functions, and then you *register* (aka hook or bind) the functions to the JavaScript engine, and then at some point later, when it is appropriate, the engine runs your code. The *engine* is the caller and is in control, not you.  Declarative programming involves callbacks and looks like this (fictional code):

```
dbFactory.newConnection(function onConnect(dbConn) {
  dbConn.newTransaction(function onNewTransaction(tx) {
    tx.put(myObject, function onPut(resultCode) {
      if(resultCode == dbResultConstants.ERROR_PUT_KEY_EXISTS) {
        alert('uhoh');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In this example, the only thing *you* called was the fictional dbFactory.newConnection function. You passed in a callback function. You did not call the callback function yourself. The engine calls the callback function. You cannot call the callback function yourself. This is kind of the whole idea behind why JavaScript engines can allow you to write asynchronous code. Because you don't get to control the order of execution of statements/functions. The engine gets to control it. All you get to do is write your functions, register them, and then start a chain of callbacks (the sole imperative line, the starting statement).

So this is why a function like `getObjectStore` in your question will not work. You are trying to call the function yourself, but that is backwards. You can only write a function and register it (somehow hook it up as a callback somewhere) and then the *engine*, not you, calls it at some later point in time.

Hopefully this is not more confusing, but you could actually write your function `getObjectStore` if you really wanted to by passing in the database variable to the function as its first argument. This leads to the logical next question, how to get a valid database variable to pass into the function. You cannot get one in a global context (reliably). Because the connection variable is only valid within the context of the onOpen callback function. So you would have to make your call to this function from within the onOpen function. Something like:

```
function getObjectStore(db, name, mode) {
  var tx = db.transaction(name, mode);
  var store = tx.objectStore(name);
  return store;
}

var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
openRequest.onsuccess = function onOpen(event) {
  // get the connection variable. it is defined within this (onOpen) function and open.
  var db = this.result;

  // call our simple imperative helper function to get the users store. only call it from
  // within this onOpen function because that is the only place we can get the 'db' variable.
  var usersStore = getObjectStore(db, 'users', 'readwrite');

  // do something here with usersStore, inside this function only.
};
```

Comment: Kudos Josh! This is a really great answer!

Comment: FYI, the comment on using `setTimeout` was not advice to `fix` the problem but advice to `see` the problem.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I did not mean to sound rude. Apologies.

Comment: The advice to use `setTimeout` made me realize there was actually nothing wrong with my code, I was merely trying to call something before it was done. My code works and has been working because of that advice.

Comment: This must be the longest SO answer!  +1